# if li has ul in ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

If `li` has `ul`, then append `+` to the this `li` closest class `- .submenu`. This **jQuery** function is working on the same page, but when I try to use this function on `ajax` loaded content, it does not work. How can it be used properly after `ajax` load?

```js
$('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
    if($(this).children("ul").length){
        $(this).find('.submenu').html("+");
    }
});
$(document).on("click", ".submenu", function(){
    $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style:none;
}
ul li ul{
  display:none;
}
.cursorpointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='submenu cursorpointer'></span>
        <input type='radio' name='menu_id' value='sport'>Sports
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type='checkbox' name='subnav[]' value='fb'>Football
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type='checkbox' name='subnav[]' value='vb'>Volleyball
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='submenu cursorpointer'></span>
        <input type='radio' name='menu_id' value='vehicle'>Vehicle
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type='checkbox' name='subnav[]' value='car'>Car
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type='checkbox' name='subnav[]' value='cycle'>Cycle
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i may have a look at the jQuery method [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete
>   event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the
>   .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

your code shall look like this:

```
 var url = "http://....",
 container = $(".AjaxContainer");

$.ajax({
url: url,
type : 'get',
complete : function( qXHR, textStatus ) {           
    if (textStatus === 'success') {
        var data = qXHR.responseText 
        container.append(data); 
        $('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
            if($(this).children("ul").length){
                $(this).find('.submenu').html("+");
            }
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".submenu", function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind events after ajax `success` handler.

do this

```
success :function(data){
 //your code what you do with data in success.

  $('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
    if($(this).children("ul").length){
        $(this).find('.submenu').html("+");
    }
 });

 $(document).off("click", ".submenu");
 $(document).on("click", ".submenu", function(){
    $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle("slow");
 });
}
```

I assume your DOM is getting elements dynamically added after `ajax` request. That is why we need to put the code here (in `success`) as well.

**Note** - Do not forget to unbind click event from `.submenu` to prevent multiple events registration. As you can see I've put `.off` to unbind event before it gets registered, That way you will only get one event registration at a time which is a `.click` event in your case.

Comment: oh I see, Thanks!! @Manoz

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the first part of your code like this:

```
$(document).find('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
  if ($(this).children("ul").length) {
    $(this).find('.submenu').html('+');
   }
})
```